# Android, how can I change a drawable within a button dynamically?

Tags: android, button, click, drawable

So I have this method to alter the text in a button every time it is clicked:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputModeSelector);
    button1.setTag(1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final int status =(Integer) v.getTag();
            if(status == 1) {
                button1.setText("Pic");

                v.setTag(0); //pause
            } else {
                button1.setText("Text");
                v.setTag(1); //pause
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Changed Input Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

In the styling of the button I have:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_assignment_white_18dp"
```

This puts an icon to emphasize the text mode.  My question is how can I also change that icon to a different one to go along with the camera mode, or basically how can I set the drawableLeft attribute?

Comment: create a `Drawable` with several "levels": `android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable` and just set the level accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `drawableLeft` programmatically using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`, as below

```
button1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.yourdrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

Please read  the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set drawable programmatically, you have to use

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int leftDrawableId, int topDrawableId, int rightDrawableId, int bottomDrawableId);
```

So if you want to set drawable left, just give id of the drawable to the corresponding parameters of setCompoundDrawablesWithInstrinsicBounds(), and keep rest of them null or 0.
For Example :

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.textIcon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Similary, if you want to set right drawable to have to do this:

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.textIcon, 0);
```